# What is the benefit of the repeat function in CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

What is the difference between these two `grid-template-columns` property values? Are they same?

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

Comment: Yes, they are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no functional difference.

However, practically, imagine a grid with 24 or even 100 defined columns.

The `repeat()` function would certainly come in handy in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

They both represent the same. As stated in the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat()),

> The repeat() CSS function represents a repeated fragment of the track list, allowing a large number of columns or rows that exhibit a recurring pattern to be written in a more compact form.

So, basically `repeat()` is used to write a value in compact form instead of repeating the same values. I hope that might help.